# SSH Tunneling with Robot Framework-SSH LIbrary

Tags: robotframework

I am using Robot Framework SSH Library for my automation.

I need to establish SSH Tunnel to a remote machine using Robot Framework and then execute set of tests on the remote machine.

Looks like RF SSH Library do not have support for this.

Can someone point me to any other options available?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use Robot Framework to open SSH connection, copy test files, run them and copy results back.

You will need two files, first one is ssh.txt

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SSHLibrary
Suite Setup       Open Connection And Log In
Suite Teardown    Copy And Delete Files And Close Connections

*** Variables ***
${HOST}                your.server.here
${USERNAME}            username
${PASSWORD}            password

*** Testcases ***
Run Tests on remote server
    Put File                  real-test.txt
    Run Test In Server        real-test.txt
    Sleep    1s

*** Keywords ***
Open Connection And Log In
   Open Connection    ${HOST}
   Login              ${USERNAME}    ${PASSWORD}

Copy And Delete Files And Close Connections
    Copy Results From Server
    Clean Up Server    real-text.txt
    Close All Connections

Run Test In Server
    [Arguments]   ${filename}
    ${rc}=     Execute Command    pybot ${filename}    return_stdout=False  return_rc=True
    Should Be Equal As Numbers    ${rc}    0

Copy Results From Server
    GetFile    log.html
    GetFile    output.xml
    GetFile    report.html


Clean Up Server
    [Arguments]   ${filename}
    Write    rm log.html
    Write    rm output.xml
    Write    rm report.html
    Write    rm ${filename}
```

the 2nd file is where real tests are, real-test.txt:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     OperatingSystem

*** Testcases ***
Test 1
    FileShouldExist    real-test.txt
```

run this by specifying output files to avoid filename collisions when log files are copied back from server:

> pybot -o conn.xml -r conn.html -l connlog.html ssh.txt

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like this but created the functionality in Python which I then imported to Robot as a keyword.

The jist of it was:

in `SSHTunnel.py`:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
(other imports)

class SSHTunnel:
    def create_ssh_tunnel(self):
        ssh_server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
            (host, int(port)),
            ssh_username=username,
            ssh_password=pass,
            remote_bind_address=(remote_bind_host, int(remote_bind_port))
        )
        ssh_server.start()

    def stop_ssh_tunnel(self):
        ssh_server.stop()
```

Now you add the `SSHTunnel.py` file to the Robot Library and call the keyword `Create SSH Tunnel` in the beginning of the testcase (can also be in *Test Setup* or *Suite Setup*) and `Stop SSH Tunnel` at the end.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Library    SSHLibrary

Open Connection   host_server

Login With Public Key test  /test.pem  test12345

Create Local SSH Tunnel  9191  remote_host  remote_port  bind_address=127.0.0.1

#Once the connection is made you can directly access the resources in remote_host, for eg : i am trying to connect mysql db in remote host

Connect To Database Using Custom Params   pymysql database='testDb', user='testuser', password='test123', host='127.0.0.1', port=9191
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with the help of 'local port forwarding' feature.

Ref: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding.

1. Use this command on the test server(where the robot is running) in an instance:

   `ssh -4 -L <listening_port/forwarding_port>:<destination_ip>:destination_port> username@jump_box.com`

eg)
`ssh -4 -L 50025:10.122.56.45:23 anishg@jumpbox.teski.com`

2. Use the following command in another instance to work in the destination server:

   `telnet localhost <listening port>`

eg)
`telnet localhost 50025`

Here you can execute the commands as like you are working on the destination server, as the session is opened.

In Robot, this can be achieved by this way also:

1. The Step (1) - Port forwarding is done in a shell script and this shell script is called in your robot framework.
2. Do Telnet/other in localhost with port specified

sample.sh:

`ssh -4 -L 50025:10.122.56.45:23 anishg@jumpbox.teski.com`

Robot Code:

`*** Test Cases ***
Port Forwarding
    Start Process   ./sample.sh shell=True        #Port is opened
    Log To Console  SHELL IS Executing
    Telnet.Open Connection      localhost   port=50025   #Normal op as in destn server`

Note: I used jump_box as I dont have access to destination server from my test instance.